# Rails - How to send front-end javascript data retrieved from an external API to the controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, google-maps, yelp

As the question states, I want to retrieve some coordinates from an external API (the google maps API) and send it to my controller. Currently I am using jQuery/Ajax but I am getting a 500 internal server error. I googled the error and it appears that I may be making a cross-domain ajax request. Here is the relevant javascript and controller code:

Javascript:

```
//google maps API code goes here. The points variable ultimately gives me an object with an array of coorindates. 
var points = polyline.GetPointsAtDistance(16000);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/pages/calculate',
    mydata: points,
    success: function(response) {
    //do something with the response here
    }
});
```

Controller:

```
def calculate
    x = params[:mydata]
    #do something with x ...
end
```

Is it possible to send this javascript data to my controller? Can I somehow submit the data using a hidden form instead? Or, if I want to manipulate the google maps data on the backend, do I have to use a google maps gem and perform all my data manipulation on the backend?

Comment: Can you post the response . I mean error with data

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to get data from an external API, consider setting up an ActiveResource for that.  Doing this will make the data available for you to both manipulate as needed and provide to controller/views.

Check here for more details:
[http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.1/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html]

Or you could just use an already built Gem...

Comment: Thanks for the response. I need to look into ActiveResources. One detail I left out of my original post was that I am using a javascript library called epoly.js to generate the coordinates along the route created by the google maps API. So, it seems like if I were to use ActiveResources to query the google maps API (or use a gem), I would somehow still have to send that data to my javascript file to manipulate it with the epoly.js library, then send the coordinates back to my controller. Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: making the data available in a view via a controller will also give you the ability to work with it in you epoly.js library.